# absolute position div height not increasing

Tags: html, css

in the following code, I am trying to increase the height of the `.dropdown` (grey colored one) that is placed below its parent div `content-small` (green colored one). I noticed that when I try to increase the height beyond 50px, nothing happens. I don't know why. Here I am trying to practice dropdown menu.

```css
*{
    box-sizing:border-box;
}

a {
 color: rgba(0,0,0,1);
 text-decoration: none;  
}

a:hover {
 color: rgba(0,0,255,1); 
}

html,body {
 margin: 0px;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 left: 0px;
 top: 0px;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,1);
 padding: 0px;
    }



.wrapper {
 height: 600px;
 max-width: 960px;
 margin-left: auto;
 left: 0px;
 top: 0px;
 background-color: rgba(204,204,204,1);
 margin-right: auto;
 position: relative;
 padding: 0px;
 margin-top: 0px;
}


.content {
 position: relative;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 height: 100%;
 max-height: 200px;
 max-width: 600px;
 background-color: #FFF;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-top: 0px;
 left: 0px;
 right: 0px;
 font-size: 32px;
 text-align: center;
 border: 3px solid rgba(0,0,0,1);
 border-radius: 15px 15px 0px 0px;
 width: 100%;
}

.content-small {
 max-width: 100px;
 height: 100%;
 max-height: 50px;
 background-color: rgba(0,255,204,1);
 position: relative;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
 border: 3px solid rgba(0,0,0,1);
 top: 5px;
}

.dropdown {
 box-sizing: border-box;
 width: 100px;
 max-width: 100px;
 height: 100%;
 max-height: 50px;
 background-color: rgba(214,214,214,1);
 position: absolute;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
 border: 3px solid rgba(255,0,0,1);
 top: 47px;
 left: -3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="content">
<div class="content-small">
Home
<div class="dropdown">
</div>
</div>


</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Because you set the max-height to 50px

Comment: you mean the max height of parent div or the child div?

Comment: @pure_coder the max-height of the `dropdown` div.

Comment: It works. But the problem is that I am using max-height because I want the div to scale down whenever the browser window is scaled down. So I have to use the max-height property. What is the other work around for this?

Answer (score 1):

It's inheriting the `max-height` attribute from its `.content-small` parent. Similarly `.content-small` can only have maximum dimensions of the `.content` div.

Comment: so then how can I have the child div's height more than the parents? And I  don't want to remove max-height also. Whats the alternative

Comment: Since you are using absolute positioning anyway you not nest the .dropdown div inside .content-small. Inheritance cannot be turned off.